# SSH Using Wrong ID

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, centos, public-key-encryption

I am trying to establish password-less ssh to myself on a CentOS6 system.  I go through the following steps:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The appropriate public and private key files, as well as authorized keys are all created.  The contents of ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub is shown below:

> ssh-dss
>   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
>   admin-cloud@computer.network.net

However, when I then run a "ssh computer.network.net" or "ssh localhost" command, I am prompted for a password (first problem).  After entering the password and establishing the ssh session, I exit and inspect the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, where the following key has been cached:

> localhost ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEApHXsA7mMOtqKO1XotKTk5vM5F1LRoqxLLZw2TVLUA36BrkJAMM1EqfnH3mIoNz6sJzOdmQV2ubYGkzvCUb1TX8wUId1KQki8I1l2S52vFEwHkJlFe+KFQcU4SBtxDRDEvHkiLid0D37V+O3W6ElxhhRjkL+nebFPSFEdDlwBUTzAmR3KPD9zFjLP3JJZrwYH1E1sEl52pHbrcr7ROhfRjtz+3glVog9tJC3Xbfwu74JeywYrKQXbtDV84CJ0FoD6WAtJ+V0Dh8hnyBDkdbBc/zVIEDcXfcVNA4yc2noAHdQQ6p11Q8zW94/aJVhi/t0D9vSVMZP8UbHmnM2RfElIww==

which is an RSA key, not the DSA key I generated (second problem).  After doing some digging I found this RSA key in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub.

**Why is SSH using the keys in the /etc/ssh folder and not the keys I generated in the ~/.ssh folder?**  How can I tell SSH to use the public private key pair in the ~/.ssh folder.  A look at man ssh seems to indicate this is the default behaviour but is clearly not happening.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Output of trying ssh -v localhost is verbose but I did find one interesting tidbit:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/admin-cloud/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 434
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/admin-cloud/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/admin-cloud/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

So it looks like it find my ~/.ssh/id_dsa key, gets accepted, and then comes the "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key".  After that it looks for ~/.ssh/identity (doesn't exist) and ~/.ssh/id_rsa (doesn't exist) and then finally, just asks for a password.  Any idea about that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **authorized_keys** file should contain the *public* key, not the *private* one.  The following command should have used the **id_dsa.pub** file instead:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The **known_hosts** file is for host keys, so that is as expected.

Furthermore, try adding one or more **-v** flags when running **ssh**, it will print lots of useful info.

**Edit:** Can you verify what keys *ssh-agent* has cached by using: **ssh-add -L** ?

Or run **ssh-add** (or **ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa**) to ensure that the file on disk matches its cache and try again.

Comment: apologies, that was a typo. I am adding the public key to the authorized_keys file.  If I had cated the private key it would have a ----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY---- banner across the top

Comment: ssh-add fixed it.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of your `IdentityFile` configuration variable in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, and ensure it is not overridden by `~/.ssh/config`:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

And, just to be sure (it should be redundant, `ssh-keygen` creates it with the correct permissions), verify that permissions on that file are 0600, or `ssh` won't use the file.

> Specifies a file from which the user's DSA, ECDSA or RSA
>   authentication identity is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity  for
>   protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa and
>   ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2.  Additionally, any  identities
>   represented by the authentication agent will be used for
>   authentication.  ssh(1) will try to load certificate  information from
>   the filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to the path of a
>   specified IdentityFile.
>
> The file name may use the tilde syntax to refer to a user's home
>   directory or one of the following escape characters: ‘%d’  (local
>   user's home directory), ‘%u’ (local user name), ‘%l’ (local host
>   name), ‘%h’ (remote host name) or ‘%r’ (remote user  name).
>
> It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in
>   configuration files; all these identities will be tried in  sequence. 
>   Multiple IdentityFile directives will add to the list of identities
>   tried (this behaviour differs from that of  other configuration
>   directives).